# How can I port this Java code to C#?

Tags: c#, java, design-patterns, reflection

I am looking at a pattern implemented in Java and have some questions about how it aligns to (can be ported to) C#.

Java:

```
class Foo
{
    private Class someClass;
    ...
}

class Bar
{
    private Field some Field;
}
```

First, Class stores an instance of a domain object.  It looks like Java exposes reflection methods on the type which are used to access fields on the object through reflection.  What would type would be synonymous in C#?  Would I use object and then use MethodInfo or is there a better way?

Second, Field is type in the framework and is assigned by using:

```
someClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName)
```

Is there a parallel in the .NET framework i should use?

Right now I created a custom object in place of the Class in Foo, and I created a custom object for Field.  Is there a preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may take a look at the [FieldInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo(VS.71).aspx) type and [GetField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332471(VS.71).aspx) method.

Code might look something among the lines:

```
class Foo
{
    public Type someClass;
    ...
}

class Bar
{
    private FieldInfo some_Field;

    public Assign(string fieldName)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        some_Field = foo.someClass.GetField(fieldName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also get the value of the field by using:

```
 foo.GetType().GetField("name").GetValue(foo).ToString()
```

In this example, we assume class foo has a field named "name". What does this help? Well think it as this way:

```
private string getValueOfUnknownField(string fieldName)
{
    return(foo.GetType().GetField(fieldName).GetValue(foo).ToString());
}
```

Even if you change class foo and add new fields to it, you don't need to change getValueOfUnknownField method.